# signed shifting

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

How can I implement signed shifting in C++? For example this code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int bit_number( int x){
 int total=0;
 while(x){
  total++;
  x>>=1;
 }

 return total;
}

int main(){
 int x=10;
 //cout<<bit_number(x)<<endl;
 int a=bit_number(x);
 int b=2*a;
 x<<=(b-a);
 x=x>>>(b-a);

 while(x!=0){
  int k=x%2;
  x=x>>1;
  cout<<k<<endl;
 }

 return 0;
}
```

shows me this error:

```
Error   1   error C2059: syntax error : '>' c:\users\datuashvili\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\binst\binst\binst.cpp    19  1   Binst
```

I know that in java there is signed shift, what about C++? How can I do it?

Comment: `>>` may implement a sign preserving right shift; it's implementation-defined. What is important about the result? If it's the value, you may want a simple arithmetic operation that more accurately reflects your intent.

Comment: Why the downvote? Do we have a problem with people asking questions now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ "knows" shifting for signed integers, however, the result is implementation-defined.

In C++, `>>` denotes shifting (for unsigned and signed types). So, the compiler interprets your `>>>` as `>>` followed by `>` (or the other way around).

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 >>> on line 19 (see your error message)

Comment: I guess that's his question. Java has a `>>>` operator (unsigned right shift, always inserts a 0 in the leftmost bit)

Comment: A `>>>` operator in a language that is so vehemently against operator overloading is just hilarious.

Comment: @jalf Yeah Isn't it great that in C++ you can't reliably use >> without a lot of additional thought (well most people just introduce bugs) because you don't know whether you get an arithmetic or logical shift? I'd love to see a gcc version that just interpreted unsigned shifts as arithmetic and signed shifts as logical shifts - oh that'd be fun :D If you need conventions to make an operator useful, it should be part of the spec.

Comment: @Voo: actually, I meant that it's ironic that Java's rationale for not allowing operator overload is that it gets abused to define surprising or unintuitive operators. And then the language itself goes and adds an arbitrary `>>>` operator because `>>` just "aint good enough".

Comment: ahh, I didn't realise java has >>> as an operator!

Comment: @jalf The whole point IS that `>>` isn't good enough (in Java). In c/c++ we'd expect the usual signed/unsigned difference - which while not guaranteed by the spec is implemented that way in every compiler because it's the only way to use right shifts sensibly (well you can usually fix the problems with some complicated additional bit arithmetic). Java doesn't allow custom operator overloading because in 98 out of 100 cases people abuse it and it's trivial to implement differently. That's obviously not the case for basic funtionality.

Comment: @Voo: you're missing the point. Many people are not aware that `>>>` exist, and from looking at the operator, it is completely unclear what it does. So it is subject to the same criticism as overloaded operators. They abused an operator just because "this ought to be an operator", which is no better than people who abuse operator overloading because "this ought to be an operator".

Comment: @jalf The difference is that the additional operator is **adding** functionality contrary to operator overloading. In languages with signed/unsigned types we could specify the usual conventions in C (has the usual problems of mixed arithmetic but is clearly defined), but without that introducing another operator is the only possibility. So it'd be like saying "some people don't know what classes are so better leave them out not to confuse them".

Comment: @Voo: bwuh? When you overload an operator, you also add functionality. An operator is nothing more than a function with a different syntax. Any time you define a function, you add functionality. Whether you define it as a regular named function, or as an overload of an existing operator, or as a completely new operator, it is new functionality that is being **added**. And introducing another operator is certainly not the only possiblity. Have you heard of "functions"? I believe they're fairly popular in some circles. They could simply have defined a `shiftRight(int, int)`.

Comment: @jalf So you mean they should've implemented a `public native (!) static long shiftRight(long, long)` and ALL its other variants? For a simple right shift? Yeah I assume they could - I mean the symmetry of this is just great. But don't forget that inlining wasn't especially great at the beginnings so we're talking about gigantic overheads for a simple shift operator. So sure they could've added that functionality (we're talking about functionality wrt to the LS obviously) your way too, but I doubt you'll find even one person thinking that to be a good idea..